# Django unit test - How to assert that a custom Manager calls the UserManager.create_user method?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking

I'm a newcomer to unit tests and mocking in Python, and in Django too.

Here is my model (simplified):

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class KangaUserManager(models.Manager):
    def create(self, username, email, password, last_name, first_name, request, registered=True, send_confirmation=True):
        kanga_user = KangaUser()
        kanga_user.user = User.objects.create_user(
            username=username,
            email=email,
            password=password,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name
        )
        return kanga_user

class KangaUser(models.Model):
    objects = KangaUserManager()

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

I would like to assert that the User.objects.create_user is called, without actually calling it. I see that the mock library is the one to use, I think, but I don't get to anything.

I tried things like that :

```
def test_create(self):
    with mock.patch('django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager') as usermanager_mock:
        kangauser_manager = KangaUserManager()
        kangauser_manager.create(self.username, self.email, self.password, self.last_name, self.first_name, self.request, self.registered, self.send_confirmation)

        self.assertTrue(usermanager_mock.create_user.called)
```

and that (and many more things I can't remeber :D)

```
def test_create(self):
    with mock.patch('django.contrib.auth.models.User') as user_mock:
        user_mock.objects = mock.MagicMock()
        user_mock.objects.create_user = mock.MagicMock()

        kangauser_manager = KangaUserManager()
        kangauser_manager.create(self.username, self.email, self.password, self.last_name, self.first_name, self.request, self.registered, self.send_confirmation)

        self.assertTrue(user_mock.objects.create_user.called)
```

But I always end up seeing that the method is not called

What am I doing wrong ?

(edit 1: added some imports)

Edit 2 :

When making the adaptation suggested by Alex martelli, I stumbled into another error,

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "<MagicMock name='User.objects.create_user()' id='55229392'>": "KangaUser.user" must be a "User" instance.
```

Here is the adapted code :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import models as auth_model


class KangaUserManager(models.Manager):
    def create(self, username, email, password, last_name, first_name, request, registered=True, send_confirmation=True):
        kanga_user = KangaUser()
        kanga_user.user = auth_model.User.objects.create_user(
            username=username,
            email=email,
            password=password,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name
        )
        return kanga_user

class KangaUser(models.Model):
    objects = KangaUserManager()

    user = models.OneToOneField(auth_model.User)
```

Comment: You're subclassing `models.Manager` but calling `Users.something` rather than `models.User.something`.  This suggests your code under test has imported `User` directly as well as `models`, and mocking a directly imported class (can be done but) is harder.  Can you just change your code under test to call `models.User`?  Otherwise you'll have to mock `User` **in your code under test** rather than in the `django` package hierarchy (a typical issue with mocking, BTW).

Comment: I can try, but the problem (and I haven't put it in the code I showed, I should edit it to make it clearer, it's that the models are from different modules, beeing from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User I will try using aliases for the imports. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, thanks to Alex and Aaron, I got the lead I needed to make it work like I wanted, thanks !

So, here is the code

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import models as auth_model


class KangaUserManager(models.Manager):
    def create(self, username, email, password, last_name, first_name, request, registered=True, send_confirmation=True):
        kanga_user = KangaUser()
        kanga_user.user = auth_model.User.objects.create_user(
            username=username,
            email=email,
            password=password,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name
        )
        return kanga_user

class KangaUser(models.Model):
    objects = KangaUserManager()

    user = models.OneToOneField(auth_model.User)
```

And the test that works :

```
def test_create(self):
    with mock.patch('django.contrib.auth.models.User') as user_mock:
        user_mock.objects = mock.MagicMock()
        user_mock.objects.create_user = mock.MagicMock()
        user_mock.objects.create_user.return_value = User()

        kangauser_manager = KangaUserManager()
        kangauser_manager.create(self.username, self.email, self.password, self.last_name, self.first_name, self.request, self.registered, self.send_confirmation)

        self.assertTrue(user_mock.objects.create_user.called)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a value when using MagicMock.

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

thing = KangaUserManager()
thing.create_user = MagicMock(return_value=True)
self.assertTrue(thing.create_user(**user_kwargs))
```